# How to join Images by depth values in Vulkan

Tags: gpu, vulkan, multi-gpu

I want to enable heterogenous multi-GPU support for my Vulkan Application. My goal is to enhance the amount of draw calls (and thereby visible objects) without increasing frame times. I decided it would be best to divide the geometry to multiple GPUs and let each one render its part to the GPU's local Framebuffer. Each local Framebuffer (including depth buffer) would be copied to the logical device containing the presentation engine at the end of the frame.

Is there any way to "join" those Framebuffers depending on the depth values? The pixel value of the framebuffer containing the least depth value should be copied to the final output Frambuffer. A version of `vkCmdBlitImage` containing a parameter of type `VkCompareOp` would be nice to have.

Comment: By "render distance", do you mean effectively having more depth precision than a 32-bit floating-point depth buffer would allow for (which, BTW, is quite a lot)? Doesn't that mean that one framebuffer is rendered with geometry that is farther away than the nearer framebuffer? That is, one of them is *always* in front of the other.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorting geometry by depth (on a per-draw basis) could be another solution to this problem. My original proposal was that drawing 1000 objects on a single GPU takes 16.6ms. If i have 2 GPUs, i can draw 2000 objects while still achieving 60fps. Those additional 1000 objects would be further away from the Camera since i would start culling objects far away first in order to achieve 60fps. When using your approach, how could i avoid that the clear color of the nearer fbo (containing no geometry and thereby being transparent) would occluding the farther geometry when blitting?

Comment: Lots of assumptions here ... have you used a profiler to confirm you are definitely limited by GPU draw/geometry performance on your original render? If you are, is the problem definitely GPU and not CPU?

Comment: ""Is there any way to "join" those Framebuffers depending on the depth values?"" - just draw a full screen quad and set `gl_FragDepth` in the fragment shader ¯|_(ツ)_/¯